# Django CSRF cookie not being set inside iframe

Tags: django, http, iframe, csrf

Short story, I need my Django site to be used by a bunch third party sites. I was able to get the site to display inside iframes by using [django-csp](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/). But whenever I need any user to use a form, the main problem being the login, I get a CSRF verification error that's caused because the `csrftoken` cookie is not being created when the page is loaded inside an iframe. Also, I suspect any AJAX request made by the site will also fail as they required CSRF validations.

I have already tried the following settings:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['mydomain.com', 'examplethirdparty.com']
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

It still doesn't work, I have read the [Django documentation regarding CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-samesite) and I found nothing else about this matter. I know I can disable CSRF protection but that's not an option for me.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: Did you see this: [Setting the token on the AJAX request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)

Comment: I did, but that's used to set the token in the AJAX request by using an existing cookie. My problem is that the cookie doesn't even exist